# Concatenate matrix of matrices in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a matrix that I am building up block-wise, like so:

```
parts = Matrix{SparseMatrixCSC{Float64}}(undef, r, r)
for i in 1:r
    for k in 1:r
        parts[i, k] = make_part(i, k)
    end
end
```

Now I'd like to concatenate all these parts into a larger matrix, with each block in its place. Is there a way to do this using the concatenation functions in `Base`? I can't figure out how to use `cat` to do it. For example, `reduce((a, acc) -> cat(acc, a, dims=(1, 2), parts)` will create a block-diagonal matrix with `r^2` blocks on the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the official command for this is `hvcat`, which is what's used to digest literal matrix syntax. Although whether it's the best solution may depend e.g. on how big theproblem is.

```
julia> parts = [fill(i + 10j, 2,2) for i in 1:2, j in 1:3]
2×3 Matrix{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [11 11; 11 11]  [21 21; 21 21]  [31 31; 31 31]
 [12 12; 12 12]  [22 22; 22 22]  [32 32; 32 32]

julia> parts[end] = [91 92; 93 94]  # secretly calls hvcat
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 91  92
 93  94

julia> hvcat(3, permutedims(parts)...)  # note that it works along the rows!
4×6 Matrix{Int64}:
 11  11  21  21  31  31
 11  11  21  21  31  31
 12  12  22  22  91  92
 12  12  22  22  93  94

julia> parts = [sprand(2,2,0.7) for i in 1:2, j in 1:3];

julia> hvcat(3, permutedims(parts)...) |> summary  # preserves sparseness
"4×6 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64} with 17 stored entries"
```

Comment: nice! Can you clarify what you mean by depending on how big the problem is? Are you referring specifically to the `permutedims` call?

Comment: The lore is that splats (`...`) are slow, except for short tuples, but not as bad as they were. And I'm not certain the whole function is designed to be fast, rather than just being designed for parsing literal matrices. So if speed matters, then you'd have to time it. I believe that the `BlockMatrix` mentioned is lazy, it just wraps the original data instead of copying it, and that it preserves blocks under some operations, which could make it fast.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have something like:

```
parts = [sprand(2,2,0.7) for i in 1:2, j in 1:3]
2×3 Matrix{SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64}}:
…
```

than `using BlockArrays` you can do:

```
julia> mortar(parts)
2×3-blocked 4×6 BlockMatrix{Float64, Matrix{SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64}}, Tuple{BlockedUnitRange{Vector{Int64}}, BlockedUnitRange{Vector{Int64}}}}:
  ⋅        0.543703  │   ⋅       0.773536  │  0.390049  0.0287028
 0.113945  0.422259  │   ⋅       0.764168  │  0.140334   ⋅
 ────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────
 0.295535  0.286277  │  0.81173   ⋅        │  0.646139  0.0616408
 0.641121  0.033793  │   ⋅       0.754504  │  0.995975   ⋅
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by a nesting `vcat` and `hcat` like so:

```
reduce(vcat, [
    reduce(hcat, [parts[i, k] for k in 1:r])
    for i in 1:r
])
```

However, this doesn't nicely generalize to higher dimensions (although I guess you could nest further loops and use plain `cat`). It will also allocate for each block row, rather than only allocating once for the entire result.